# nodejs: calculate distance from location to user

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, geojson

I'm building an API that stores locations (with their coordinates), and I want to query them based on their distance to the user.

In my view controller, i have this code:

```
var geolocation = angular.module('geolocation', []);        
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(render);
        var lat, lon = 0;
        function render(pos) {
            lat = pos.coords.latitude;
            lon = pos.coords.longitude;
            console.log(lat +","+ lon);
        }
```

That returns the user current position.
My schema is modeled like this:

```
var LocationSchema = new Schema({
  locationName: {
    type: String,
    Required: 'Enter the name of the location.'
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    Required: 'Enter the description of the location.'
  },
geolocation: { 
    type: { type: String, default:"Point" }, 
    coordinates: [Number], 
  },
```

And in my APIcontroller, i tried to do this:

```
  exports.find_all_locations_near = function(req, res) {
  Location.find({
    geolocation:
      { 
        $near :
        {
            $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ lat, lon ] },
            $minDistance: req.body.minDistance,
            $maxDistance: req.body.maxDistance
        }
      }
  }), function(err, location) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    else if (location =='')
      //res.json({ message: 'No location was found.' });
      console.log('No location was found.');
    else
      res.json(location);    
  };
}
```

I'm submitting the min and max distances this way:

```
<div class="form-group">                        
                        <label>Min Distance</label> <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" ng-model="formData.minDistance"><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">                        
                        <label>Max Distance</label> <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" ng-model="formData.maxDistance"><br>
                    </div>
```

But nothing happens. I get 0 results. What am I doing wrong?
Also, how can i calculate the distance between the user and a location and return that on each row?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that while storing coordinates, longitude should come first and then latitude. If that looks confusing, [you could store the coordinates as an embedded document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/#geospatial-indexes-geohash) too with keys as `lng` & `lat`.

[Querying GeoJson Data](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#query-on-geojson-data)